# R data.tree package: how to specify direction (parent to child, or the other way)

Tags: r, tree

the package doc `?FromDataFrameNetwork` says how to specify the direction

> This can be either climbing (from parent to children) or descending
>   (from child to parent)

Q1. why `direction = "descen"` doesn't work:

```
library(data.tree)
data(acme)

x = ToDataFrameNetwork(acme, direction = "climb")
head(x)
# from                       to
# 1  Acme Inc.               Accounting
# 2  Acme Inc.                 Research
# 3  Acme Inc.                       IT
# 4 Accounting             New Software
# 5 Accounting New Accounting Standards
# 6   Research         New Product Line

x = ToDataFrameNetwork(acme, direction = "descen")
# Error in ToDataFrameNetwork(acme, direction = "descen") : 
#         direction descen unknown. Must be either climb or descen.

#of course i can manually make it from child to parent:
x_the_other_way = x[ , c('to', 'from')]
head(x_the_other_way)
#                       to       from
# 1               Accounting  Acme Inc.
# 2                 Research  Acme Inc.
# 3                       IT  Acme Inc.
# 4             New Software Accounting
# 5 New Accounting Standards Accounting
# 6         New Product Line   Research
```

Q2. how to specify direction when converting a dataframe network into a tree?

```
xN <- FromDataFrameNetwork(x, direction = "climb")
# Error in FromDataFrameNetwork(x, direction = "climb") : 
#         unused argument (direction = "climb")
```

Update about Q2: The algorithm will figure out the direction; the user doesn't need to specify. I guess it may figure it out based on "there's only one root"

```
xN = FromDataFrameNetwork(x)
xN_the_other_way = FromDataFrameNetwork(x_the_other_way)

xN
# levelName
# 1  Acme Inc.                       
# 2   ¦--Accounting                  
# 3   ¦   ¦--New Software            
# 4   ¦   °--New Accounting Standards
# 5   ¦--Research                    
# 6   ¦   ¦--New Product Line        
# 7   ¦   °--New Labs                
# 8   °--IT                          
# 9       ¦--Outsource               
# 10      ¦--Go agile                
# 11      °--Switch to R  

xN_the_other_way
# levelName
# 1  Acme Inc.                       
# 2   ¦--Accounting                  
# 3   ¦   ¦--New Software            
# 4   ¦   °--New Accounting Standards
# 5   ¦--Research                    
# 6   ¦   ¦--New Product Line        
# 7   ¦   °--New Labs                
# 8   °--IT                          
# 9       ¦--Outsource               
# 10      ¦--Go agile                
# 11      °--Switch to R
```

Thank you-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help for `ToDataFrameNetwork` says:

```
?ToDataFrameNetwork
direction   when converting to a network, should the edges point from root to children ("climb") or from child to parent ("descend")?
```

So you must specify either `climb` or `descend`.

(There is a typo in the error message, it's already fixed in github, not yet on CRAN).

Regarding your second question: Yes, the network provided in the first two columns must be a tree, i.e. it can contain only one root. Hence, it's simple for the algorithm to find out which direction the network is specified in.